# Azure Logic App Partition key [X] is invalid with COsmos Db

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to save JSON parsed data to Cosmos Db, HTTP trigger works as it should as well as parsing but getting `Partition key [my_dynamic_key_value] is invalid`.

Did anyone have a similar issue?
I have found this article [link](https://marcelzehner.ch/2019/02/05/issues-with-creating-new-cosmos-db-documents-with-logic-app/) but still getting the same error.

Thanks

EDIT 1

This is the flow for adding item to DB
[image: cosmos db flow]

Schema:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Groups": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "JobName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Link": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "MinSalary": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "MaxSalary": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Hours": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "WorkPattern": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Details": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "Detail": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "Name",
                        "Detail"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "id",
            "Groups",
            "JobName",
            "Link",
            "MinSalary",
            "MaxSalary",
            "Hours",
            "WorkPattern",
            "Details"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is a response:

```
{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Partition key [1bb2d44f-a066-4fa8-8a78-0cdcea1a756c] is invalid.\r\nActivityId: 345f9a99-534b-40cb-9dc0-9863dc8c90f5, \r\nRequestStartTime: 2020-04-28T08:04:46.8249255Z, RequestEndTime: 2020-04-28T08:04:46.8249255Z,  Number of regions attempted:1\r\n, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.10.0"
}
```

Comment: Will you provide the schema (or an example if dynamic) of an HTTP request sent to your trigger (I assume you mean HTTP rather than HTML)? Also, provide an example of the schema used in your Cosmos DB action.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Just added details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the partition key in the double quotes. Refer to sample screen shot below
[image]

Comment: that's it. Thank you! Funny as I have tried with static string to test if that's the case but it didn't work :/ example "MyTestKey". Your resolution works, brilliant.

Comment: I know  :)  spent some time myself scratching  my head on this one